# astar algorithm is expanding like bfs . where is my failure?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, a-star

I am currently working on a project to visualize different graph search algorithms. I have implemented an A* algorithm, but for some reason, it seems to be expanding nodes in a similar manner to the BFS algorithm. I have provided my A* algorithm code in this CodePen link: https://codepen.io/dilsoziya/pen/KKGeqdP

astar expanding nodes:
[astar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abZ7r.png)

bfs expanding nodes:
[bfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxHlp.png)

i want that my astar is search like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVKoN.png) (Source: https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer/#)

I am seeking assistance from the Stack Overflow community to help me understand what could be causing this issue and how I can fix it. I'm having difficulty pinpointing the exact problem in the A* algorithm code, so any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

My astar Method:

```
    async astar(start, target){
        let openList = new PriorityQueue()
        let openListId = []
        let closedList = []
        openList.push(start, 0)
        openListId.push(start.x + "_" + start.y)
        this.setGCost(start.x,start.y, 0)
    
        while(!openList.isEmpty()){
            let current = openList.dePop().node
            this.removeValueFromArray(openListId, current.x + "_" + current.y)
            closedList.push(current.x + "_" + current.y)
            c.changeRectangleColor(current.x,current.y, "blue")
            await this.sleep(200)
            if(this.isEqual(current,target)){
                return []
            }
    
            const adjacent = this.getAdjacent(current.x,current.y)
            for(let i = 0;i < adjacent.length;i++){
                let neighbour = adjacent[i].end
                if(closedList.includes(neighbour.x + "_" + neighbour.y) || this.checkWall(neighbour)){
                    continue
                }
    
                let tentative_gSCore = this.getGCost(current.x, current.y) + this.distanceBetween(current,neighbour)
    
                let tentativeBetter
                if(!openListId.includes(neighbour.x + "_" + neighbour.y)){
                    openList.push(neighbour)
                    openListId.push(neighbour.x + "_"+ neighbour.y)
                    tentativeBetter = true
                }else if(tentative_gSCore < this.getGCost(neighbour.x,neighbour.y)){
                    tentativeBetter = true
                }else {
                    tentativeBetter = false
                }
    
                if(tentativeBetter){
                    this.setGCost(neighbour.x,neighbour.y,tentative_gSCore)
                    this.setHeuristic(neighbour.x,neighbour.y, this.heuristic(neighbour,target))
                    let fcost = (this.getGCost(neighbour.x,neighbour.y) + this.getHeuristic(neighbour.x,neighbour.y))
                    this.setfScore(neighbour.x,neighbour.y,fcost)
                    
                }
            }
    
        }
        return null
    }
```

Comment: *"performs the search like my bfs"*: that is quite a vague problem statement. Please, (1) add the shortest possible initialisation code that is necessary to run into the problem; (2) provide how the output differs from the expected output (3) add debugging information that proves your point.

Comment: hey @trincot i edit my post. i hope you can help me now.

Comment: Can you supply actual inputs and expected outputs (and not images of it running?)